# eclipse workspace missing projects deleted file

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Modeling Tools (Version: Indigo Service Release 2 Build id: 20120216-1857).

One of my projects in the workspace has disappeared from the Package Explorer (the View of all projects). Or better said, it is in the list, but it seems closed and when I try to open it, I get this error message: "The project description file (.project) for 'xxxxx' is missing.  This file contains important information about the project.  The project will not function properly until this file is restored."

What I really worry me: the project folder isn't available on the filesystem either.

I don't know why or how ... the only thing 'different' that I can remember is that I have switched the workspace to a new one, when that project was open.

Any idea to recover the folder/project?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you moved it by a mistake?

Check the other workspace (on filesystem) or maybe the project is in another project.
You should always do backup's or/and checkin in a VCS.

A recovery-tool can help, if the bit's are still there.
Good luck.